# What's the reason for the weird error message "package is not compatible with netstandard2.0. Package does support netstandard2.0"?

Tags: c#, .net, package, nuget, .net-standard

We are getting weird error messages during our build.

They don't make any sense, because they are wrong (see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#select-net-standard-version)):

> Error NU1202: Package XY 1.0.0 is not compatible with net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8). Package XY 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

> Error NU1201: Package XY 1.0.0 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package XY 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

and the weirdest one:

> Error NU1201: Package XY 1.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package XY 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, this was caused by referencing the same project **once as a package and once as a project**.

It happened transitively:

- Main Project -> Project 1 -> XY as package
- Main Project -> Project 2 -> XY as project

Solutions:

- Referencing it only as a package (PackageReference)
- or referencing it only as a project (ProjectReference)

It's unfortunate, that Microsoft does not log a better error message, because it took us quite some time to find out what exactly the problem is.